# How to load png's from GitHub into R?

Tags: r

For an MLB project I'm working on, I am looking to download team logos that can then be plotted on charts. I haven't found any great places for logos, but there is this GitHub account (https://github.com/klunn91/team-logos/tree/master/MLB)that has png's for each team in folders organized by sports league.

I've tried using the readPNG function to download this images into R, but with no luck because I can get the link to work in the source argument. Is anyone able to help with downloading all team logo png's into R?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and what errors you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can download GitHub files from the `https://raw.githubusercontent.com` domain, save them locally, load into R and insert them into graphics via `png::rasterImage()`.

To illustrate the approach we will download the Chicago White Sox logo from the [klunn91/team-logos](https://github.com/klunn91/team-logos) Github repository, and insert it in the lower left corner of a plot.

First, we use `download.file()` with `mode = "wb"` to download the png file as a binary file.

```
library(png)

aPNGFile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klunn91/team-logos/master/MLB/whiteSox.png"

download.file(aPNGFile,
              "./data/whiteSox.png",mode="wb")
```

Next, we use `png::readPNG()` to load it into memory.

```
soxLogo <- readPNG( "./data/whiteSox.png")
```

Finally, we create a basic plot and render the logo in the lower left portion of the data display area.

```
plot(1:2, type='n')
rasterImage(soxLogo,1,1,1.15,1.4)
```

...and the output:

[image]

### Downloading all of the MLB logos to a directory

We can use the following code to download all of the logos. First, we create a vector with the file names for each logo.

```
# download all the logos

logoList <- c("_MLB_logo","angels","astros","athletics","blueJays","braves",
              "brewers","cardinals","cubs","diamondbacks","dodgers","giants",
              "indians","mariners","marlins","mets","nationals","orioles",
              "padres","phillies","pirates","rangers","rays","redSox","reds","rockies",
              "royals","tigers","twins","whiteSox","yankees")
```

Next, we create a `./data/logos` directory to store the logo files. The `./` at the start of the directory tells R to create these directories as subdirectories of the current R working directory.

```
if(!dir.exists("./data")) dir.create("./data")
if(!dir.exists("./data/logos")) dir.create("./data/logos")
```

Next, we use the `logoList` vector to drive `lapply()` with an anonymous function that downloads the files. we use `paste0()` to build each file name as it exists in the GitHub repository, as well as the file name out the output files stored to local disk.

```
results <- lapply(logoList,function(x){
     download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klunn91/team-logos/master/MLB/",
                          x,".png"),
                   paste0("./data/logos/",x,".png"),
                          mode="wb")
})
```

We can see all the files in the directory as viewed through the MacOS Finder tool.

[image]

At this point we can read the files from disk and access them within R. First, we use `list.files()` to obtain a list of the files.

```
logoFiles <- as.list(list.files("./data/logos",pattern=".png",full.names = TRUE))
```

Next, we use `lapply()` to load the png files into a list.

```
# read the logo files into a list
logoPNGList <- lapply(logoFiles,readPNG)
```

We name the elements in the list so we can access individual logs from the list by name, via the `$` form of the extract operator.

```
# name the elements in list so we can access by name 
names(logoPNGList) <- logoList
```

Finally, we render one of the logos in a plot.

```
# render the Cubs logo in a plot, using named access to list
plot(1:2, type='n')
rasterImage(logoPNGList$cubs,1,1,1.15,1.4)
```

...and the output:

[image]

Embedding the logos in more useful graphics is left as an interesting exercise for the reader, as is scraping the HTML list of files directly from Github to use with `download.file()`.

Comment: Incredible - THANK YOU!

Comment: Hi @Eric K. I noticed you are new here. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this answer solved your problem. However, there is no obligation to do this.